# Cant track error cause in PHP page updating a MS SQL database

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, odbc

Simple PHP page (I'm no PHP expert, just learning) to update a MS SQL database.  The following code generates an error that I dont know how to solve.

```
    include '/connections/SFU.php';
$query = "UPDATE Person SET PhotoURL = '".$file["name"]."' WHERE USERID='".$_REQUEST['user_id']."';";
if ($result =  odbc_exec($dbconnect, $query)) {
    echo "// Success!";
}
else {
    echo "// Failure!";
}
odbc_close($dbconnect);
//End Update
```

This fails every time in the "if ($result ..." section

However, if I run virtually the same code

```
    include '/connections/SFU.php';
$query = "UPDATE Person SET PhotoURL = '89990.jpg' WHERE USERID='80'";
if ($result =  odbc_exec($dbconnect, $query)) {
// Success!
}
else {
// Failure!
} 
odbc_close($dbconnect);
//End Update
```

It works just fine.  I have echoed the $query string to the screen and the string is the same for both.  I can't figure out why it fails in one and not the other?

Also weird is when I use a parameterized query such as

```
include '/connections/SFU.php';
$query = "UPDATE dbo.Person SET PhotoURL=? WHERE USERID=?";
if ($res = odbc_prepare($dbconnect,$query)) {
    echo "Prepare Success";
} else {
    echo "Prepare Failed".odbc_errormsg();
}
$uid = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
$fn = $file["name"];
echo "query=".$query." userid=".$uid." filename=".$fn;  
if ($result =  odbc_exec($res, array($fn, $uid))) {     
    echo "// Success!";
}
else {
    echo odbc_errormsg();
    echo "// Failure!";
}
odbc_close($dbconnect);
```

The query fails in the prepare section above, but fails in the odbc_exec section below:

```
include '/connections/SFU.php';
$query = "UPDATE Person SET PhotoURL=? WHERE USERID=?";
if ($res = odbc_prepare($dbconnect,$query)) {
    echo "Prepare Success";
} else {
    echo "Prepare Failed".odbc_errormsg();
}
$uid = "80";
$fn = "samplefile.jpg";
echo "query=".$query." userid=".$uid." filename=".$fn;  
if ($result =  odbc_exec($res, array($fn, $uid))) {     
    echo "// Success!";
}
else {
    echo odbc_errormsg();
    echo "// Failure!";
}
odbc_close($dbconnect);
```

In all cases I do not get any odbc_errormsg ().

Comment: Please [use bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) in your code, don't just pass in raw data from the website.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `;` from your query.

```
$query = "UPDATE Person SET PhotoURL = '".$file["name"]."' WHERE
          USERID='".$_REQUEST['user_id']."';";
                                           ^
```

So your query should be,

```
$query = "UPDATE Person SET PhotoURL = '".$file["name"]."' WHERE
          USERID='".$_REQUEST['user_id'];
```

Also have practice of using `odbc_errormsg()` so you can have a better idea why your query  gets failed.

**Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to [**sql injection attacks**](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have tried it both ways (with and without) the extra ";"  I have also tried using parameters and in both cases it fails.

Comment: echo your query & check. Also have you added `odbc_errormsg();` in your else condition ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but the odbc_errormsg does not return any value.